# fatal not a git repository Windows Self-Hosted runner GitHub Actions

Tags: github, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to run git commands on windows self hosted runner which is configured on Amazon EC2 instance. I have installed the git bash on the same machine where my runner is configured and set it's path in the Environment Variables.

Now when I am running this piece of code:

```
deploy:
  needs: test # This test job is deployed on GitHub Hosted Runner
  runs-on: [ self-hosted, Windows, X64 ]
  defaults:
    run:
      shell: cmd

  steps:
    - name: Checkout code repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    
    - name: Git Commit SHA command
      shell: powershell
      run: |
        $output = C:\"Program Files"\Git\cmd\git rev-parse --short=4 HEAD
        echo $output
```

I am getting this error: **Run C:"Program Files"\Git\cmd\git rev-parse HEAD
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.**

I got the solution for this that I need to clone the repository inside the EC2 instance where the runner is configured and post that I need to run `git init` command to initialize it as a git repo but I have a reason not to clone it as being a client I don't want the third party will able to access my code.

Is there any alternative which helps me to get rid of this error?

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications SE. Both Amazon tags excerpts say "DO NOT USE". You might ask for a [se] site recommendation on [meta.se].